# Snowflake - How to create summary table containing unique records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for some Snowflake syntax assistance in how to generate a summary table or view from an existing table. My summary table should have 1 row per unique id from the existing table along with boolean values indicating if the various milestones (as per the summary column names) have been hit. Any help is appreciated as I am a Snowflake novice. Thanks.

[Existing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1C0K.png)

[Desired Summary Table/View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWiGo.png)

Comment: Please don't use links in your question. Add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: I second @NickW's comment – having the actual content directly in your Q will make it more readable + durable. Here's a guide for [putting tables in SO Q's using Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Appreciate that however as a stackoverflow newbie, i wont let me do that until I post 10 times. Using links was the only way to do it.

Comment: You should be able to edit your Q right away... @gwatsonuk -- you aren't trying to answer your Q are u?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using Himanshu's data, thank you:

```
WITH fake_data(id, updated, pipeline_id, stage_id) AS (
    SELECT column1, to_date(column2,'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), column3, column4
    FROM VALUES
        (1111, '02/01/2022 09:01:00', 'A', '1' ),
        (1111, '02/01/2022 10:01:00', 'A', '2' ),
        (1111, '02/01/2022 11:01:00', 'B', '5' ),                          
        (2222, '02/02/2022 13:01:00', 'A', '1' ),
        (2222, '02/03/2022 18:01:00', 'B', '5' ),
        (2222, '02/04/2022 07:01:00', 'B', '6' ),                                         
        (3333, '02/02/2022 14:01:00', 'A', '1' ),
        (3333, '02/03/2022 18:01:00', 'A', '2' ),
        (3333, '02/03/2022 07:01:00', 'C', '7' ),
        (3333, '02/03/2022 21:01:00', 'C', '8' ),
        (3333, '02/05/2022 17:01:00', 'C', '9' )
)
```

we are doing an aggregation across each `id` and we want to use [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) to see how many row meet out criteria, and if it is `>0` we are happy

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    count_if(pipeline_id='A')>0 AS hit_stage_a,
    count_if(pipeline_id='B')>0 AS hit_stage_b,
    count_if(pipeline_id='C')>0 AS hit_stage_c,
    count_if(stage_id='4')>0 AS hit_stage_4,
    count_if(stage_id='5')>0 AS hit_stage_5,
    count_if(stage_id='6')>0 AS hit_stage_6
FROM fake_data
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| ID | HIT_STAGE_A | HIT_STAGE_B | HIT_STAGE_C | HIT_STAGE_4 | HIT_STAGE_5 | HIT_STAGE_6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2222 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3333 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

Answer (score 2):

try this and see if this helps to get what you want.

```
SELECT ID, decode(HIT_PIPELINE_A, NULL,FALSE,TRUE) ,
           decode(HIT_PIPELINE_B, NULL,FALSE,TRUE),
           decode(HIT_PIPELINE_C, NULL,FALSE,TRUE),
           decode(HIT_STAGE_4, NULL,FALSE,TRUE),
           decode(HIT_STAGE_5, NULL,FALSE,TRUE),
           decode(HIT_STAGE_6, NULL,FALSE,TRUE) FROM 
(
SELECT * from tab1
PIVOT(MAx(PIPELINE_ID) FOR stage_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')) 
 AS P(ID,DT,HIT_PIPELINE_A,HIT_PIPELINE_B,HIT_PIPELINE_C,HIT_STAGE_4,HIT_STAGE_5,HIT_STAGE_6)
) order by ID; 

                                        
 
  
create or replace table Tab1  (ID varchar2(100), updated date, pipeline_id varchar2(100), stage_id varchar2(10));
insert into tab1 values(1111, to_date('02/01/2022 09:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'A', '1' );
insert into tab1 values(1111, to_date('02/01/2022 10:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'A', '2' );
insert into tab1 values(1111, to_date('02/01/2022 11:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'B', '5' );

insert into tab1 values(2222, to_date('02/02/2022 13:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'A', '1' );
insert into tab1 values(2222, to_date('02/03/2022 18:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'B', '5' );
insert into tab1 values(2222, to_date('02/04/2022 07:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'B', '6' );

insert into tab1 values(3333, to_date('02/02/2022 14:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'A', '1' );
insert into tab1 values(3333, to_date('02/03/2022 18:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'A', '2' );
insert into tab1 values(3333, to_date('02/03/2022 07:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'C', '7' );
insert into tab1 values(3333, to_date('02/03/2022 21:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'C', '8' );
insert into tab1 values(3333, to_date('02/05/2022 17:01:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'), 'C', '9' );
```